# Should a typescript/javascript method calculate and return css classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

We have an argument with my teammates about whether we should call from an Angular2 view, a TypeScript method (component) to calculate and return the proper css class for the view.

View

```
<div class="{{ getClass() }}"> ... </div>
```

Component

```
getClass():string {
   //some logic
   return 'myCSSclass';
}
```

The main issue is the coupling of css class names in css and ts files. Is there a recommended way to do this in some other way?

Comment: You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) too

Comment: This question is really opinion-based. There's nothing stopping you from doing so, and from what I understand Angular2 has [a different theory on styles for components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html), so you'd want to do some research there.

Answer (score 1):

just Like [YounesM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5781747/younesm) said :

```
<div [ngClass]="getClass()"> ... </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether the OP *should* be putting logic like that in a component, just how.

Comment: @Bougarfaoui El houcine  thanks but this is not the issue here.

Comment: yes You can define method from your view since the it requires some logic to return your class

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

You could use [ngClass], which takes in an array of css class names, or an object where the keys are property names and the values are booleans (usually bound to a class property or method) which determine whether the class should be applied or not.

If you want to decouple css class names from their templates, it's probably better to put the classes under a separate namespace - then, you can refer to their properties in your template without any concerns as to which property they are being mapped to.